# Unable to retrieve results for the following XPath Query:

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML syntax:

```
<Properties>
    <Property>
        <Name>Author</Name>
        <Type>Object</Type>
        <Value>somevalue</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Title</Name>
        <Type>String</Type>
        <Value>Word files</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Path</Name>
        <Type>String</Type>
        <Value>/path/subfolder/directory/somevalue.doc</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Rank</Name>
        <Type>Int64</Type>
        <Value>804</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Size</Name>
        <Type>Int64</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </Property>
</Properties>
```

Basically thats 1 such property set and I have about 10 more. I need to get access to the text in the Value node and in relative to the text() contained in the Name tag [Author,Title,Path,Rank,Size]. Essentially my XPathQueries are return a set of  tag texts.

My approach to it is like this:

XPathQuery("//Property/Name//*text()='Author']/Type/Value");

But that doesn't work man! And now I am 20 minutes away from tearing my hair apart :(

For the record, if it matters, I am using java Xpath libraries coz I am programming in Java.

Comment: where is the code that you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties/Property [Name = 'Author']/Value
```

Comment: umm..but is that the correct filepath ? I mean should not the Path be Properties/Property [Name = 'Author']/Type/Value ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do. If what you want is the text in the `<Value>` tag for a property with a given text in the `<Name>`, then I believe this should work (for `Author`):

```
//Property[./Name[contains(.,'Author')]]/Value/text()
#=> "somevalue"
```

I'm using nokogiri/ruby though and not Java though so I can't confirm that this will work with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/Property[Name = 'Author']/Value
```